# Python3 not picking bash_profile environment variables using OS X

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have defined the below environment variables in bash_profile :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/MYNAME.XXXX/Documents/MYNAME/Tools/android-sdk-macosx
export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH
```

but when i run the below python module , it does not print the environment variables defined in the bash_profile

*SimplePythonModule.py*

```
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

Output :

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

How do i import all the environment variables that defined in the bash_profile?? Please assist

Comment: Try reloading your .bash_profile with this: `source  ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: How do you "run the below python module"? Be precise. Do you run it from the command prompt? From an IDE? From a web server?

Comment: When i run the python module through terminal(command prompt) it works fine, but when it is triggered using eclipse IDE the environment variables are not being loaded..